# Arduino Display Ethernet.localIP()

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I'm trying to assign the IP Address of the device to a String variable.  When I use  `Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP())` to test it displays the IP Address in octets. If I use `String(Ethernet.localIP());` then it displays it as a decimal.

Is there a way to assign the octet format to a variable?

```
 String MyIpAddress;

 void StartNetwork()
 {
     Print("Initializing Network");
     if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
     while (1) {
       Print("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
       delay(10000);
     }
   }
   Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());        //displays: 192.168.80.134
   MyIpAddress = String(Ethernet.localIP());
   Serial.println(MyIpAddress);               //displays: 2253433024
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that the IPAddress property is an array.  One simple way to display the IP address is as follows:

```
String DisplayAddress(IPAddress address)
{
 return String(address[0]) + "." + 
        String(address[1]) + "." + 
        String(address[2]) + "." + 
        String(address[3]);
}
```

Comment: Good call! Thanks for the time-saver!

Answer (score 2):

A more lightweight approach is this:

```
char* ip2CharArray(IPAddress ip) {
  static char a[16];
  sprintf(a, "%d.%d.%d.%d", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);
  return a;
}
```

An IP address is, at maximum, 15 characters long, so a 16-character buffer suffices. Making it `static` ensures memory lifetime, so you can return it safely.

Another approach: the character buffer may be provided by the caller:

```
void ip2CharArray(IPAddress ip, char* buf) {
  sprintf(buf, "%d.%d.%d.%d", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use **toString()**
`display.drawString(0, 30, WiFi.localIP().toString());`